# Node js RESTful API calling using Angular js is not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express

I create a rest API using node js to list my mongodb database values. But i cant access that API through angular js $http method. I didnt get any idea. I am new in these area.

My node express api code is

```
app.get('/items', function(req, res, next) {

// query the data base to find all of the Items  
    Item.find({}, function(err, data){

// handle an error
        if (err) 
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
// handle an empty database by checking if the data array is empty
        else if (data.length===0) 
        {
            res.json({message: 'There are no items in the database.'});
        }
// if there are Items, return them  
        else 
        {

            //res.render('display',{ doc: data});
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Is this is the correct way to create an API in node express?.

I call the API using the following angular js script but it always shows error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://127.0.0.1:8080/items"
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      alert("success");

    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
      alert("Some error occures...!");

  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Please any one help me to solve this issue.

But Itried the following script it successfully working,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

<p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method : "GET",
    url : "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=atf6ya6bbz3v5u5q8um82pev"
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;


    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah... I shows Some error occures...!,  which is my error alert.

Comment: Its not error.. Only that failure alert...

Comment: if you don't post the error how are we supposed to know what it's failing?

Comment: Node API is working through the curl. But its not working in angular js

Comment: Actually the problem is when i calling the node api through angular js. the error script is working. It means angular fail to call api. But its not printing any errors

Comment: @jicks thats not right? The error part is executing once the API call is done and received error from API.. Error part of your API call is executing

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8080/items this is my url @Subburaj

Comment: How can i get console value in this.?

Comment: @jicks put console.log(err), it will print error in your console. post that.

Comment: @Subburaj It prints nothing....

Comment: console prints the error 304